# How to break pause condition and execute next condition in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow like Pause till date in which on pausing till the specified date if my previous conditions satisfies then pausing has to stop and should go further, in my case the workflow pauses till specified date and after that it executes other conditions

I want like while pausing itself if any change happened in system then pausing has to stop, and should execute further. Attached screen shot
[image]

Here if StatusReminder not equals to submitted then a mail will be sent to user to submit the form and pause for 2 days, between that 2 days if user submits the form then status changes into Submitted than my last condition has to trigger, but what happens means it pauses till the specified data and than executes the last conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Pause clause is included in the first `If Current Item:StatusReminder not equals Submitted` clause, then edit your workflow to run when an item is changed.  In SPD2010, you can find this on the Workflow Information page, under Start Options.

Then, when the item is changed so that `StatusReminder equals Submitted`, the workflow will run again, see your first two `If` statements as false, and move on to the final statement where `StatusReminder equals Submitted`.